# discord.py Remove all Roles from all Players

Tags: discord, discord.py

I tried to make a bot that removes all roles from each member, but it didn't work.
does anyone have an idea how I can do that?

````
async def safety(ctx,*role:discord.Role):
    for user in client.get_all_members():
        if not user.bot:
            try:
                await user.remove_roles(*role, reason=None)
            except:
                print(",,,,,")```
````

Comment: all roles or the roles you pass in the argument `role`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove **all** roles from a member

```py
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if not member.bot:
        await member.remove_roles(*member.roles)
```

if you want to remove the roles in the **role** argument

```py
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if not member.bot:
        await member.remove_roles(*role)
```

Also make sure to enable `intents.members`, [here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)